# Sliding with a mouse click

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

On every click on a Slider control of the mfc, the thumb moves towards the cursor in steps. I want to put the thumb directly at the place where I clicked and not to move it in steps. How can this be done?

Comment: Not that I know much about the topic, but should you still be doing MFC in 2012 ?

Comment: I am using directshow to develop a video processing tool. I was not able to use directshow with Qt. Do you have any other option.

Comment: @ereOn: Unfortunately there is a huge legacy code base built over it. Even at my company we also thought to migrate to QT, but it would happen a consequence of making our team completely stopped during one year or more time. I think the branch we are currently maintaining as circa 95000 files!

Comment: @ereOn - 2020 here. Still using MFC in a very large legacy code base :)

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the mouse events on the control, map the coordinates based on the origin of the control and determinate from the report of the x offset and the length of the control the position which was clicked on the bar. A problem with this solution is that you have to know the relative space that is taken by the inactive area of the control ( borders ) and take that into account, and you can only do this by experimenting.